# How to cancel a unirest request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, unirest

I have a node process running that do some unirest.get and unirest.post from time to time. I also have a type of web terminal from which I can see the overall progress of said unirest requests.

The problem is that I need to be able to cancel a specific request, but I can't find out how.

The structure is something like this:

```
var requests = [];
requests.push(unirest.post('someurl').end(somecallback));
requests.push(unirest.post('someurl').end(somecallback));
requests.push(unirest.post('someurl').end(somecallback));
```

And I want to do something like:

```
requests[1].cancel(); // but of course this method doesn't exist
```

since in this case I can't let the callback fires, since the goal is to cancel it to request the same url again, and without canceling it the callback would fire twice.

Anyone knows how to cancel/interrupt/destroy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of `unirest.post('someurl').end(some callback)` is `Request` object from [request module.](https://github.com/request/request)

So, you can use `abort` [method](https://github.com/request/request/pull/188):

```
requests[1].abort();
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) (sorry, cant vote your answer up)